# Apex Automatic backups

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

I'm using oracle apex (on autonomous db) and usually there is an automatic backup each night if the application has changed. 25 backups are kept.

It's a great feature.

However it's simply stopped working for me. I wonder if I've messed with the setting of the number of backups allowed?

The documentation says:

> About Configuring the Number of Backups
>
> By default, Application Express only retains the 25 most recent
> backups. Older backups are deleted to make room for new ones.
>
> Instance administrators can configure the number of backups per
> application, or disable automatic backups all together. To configure
> the number of backups for each application, sign in to the
> Administration Services application and navigate to Manage Instance,
> Feature Configuration, Application Development, and update the Number
> of backups per application attribute. Valid values are between 0 and
> 30. A value of zero (0) disables the backup feature.

(https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/htmdb/managing-application-backups.html#GUID-764CE12A-6EE1-457C-88A7-FDC0ED9FA827)

Its very like I've set a value of 0...and about the time it stopped working I know I did wonder if I could increase the number of backups.   However when I log into admin services ||Manage Instance || Feature Configuration the Application Development option does not appear. I cannot find it anywhere.

Has anyone got any idea where I can find it or other suggestions to address the issue?

(apex 20.2, autonomous (ATP) db)

Comment: Have you tried what is suggested in that documentation you copied ? "To configure the number of backups for each application, sign in to the Administration Services application and navigate to Manage Instance, Feature Configuration, Application Development, and update the Number of backups per application attribute."

Comment: As mentioned in my question, the documentation is not correct for this version of apex/autonomous db as I don't have this option.

Comment: I logged on and I can confirm that the "Application Development" tab is not visible under "Feature Configuration".